# How to get xml variable from T-SQL WITH AS SELECT FROM WHERE?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I need to get xml variable at stored procedure.

I try like this:

```
DECLARE @xmlDoc XML;

SET @xmlDoc = (
WITH TEMP_TABLE (NAME, AGE)
AS
(
SELECT NAME, AGE FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE id=1
)
SELECT A.NAME, A.AGE, B.JOB
FROM TEMP_TABLE AS A, ANOTHER_TABLE AS B
WHERE A.id = 1 AND B.id = 1
FOR XML AUTO
);
```

but I got error.

How can I get xml from With~ starting clause? Is it possible?

Comment: I had always more problem with tsql xml as it helped. In your place I tried to avoid it, either by doing the xml part on the client side (if it is possible, f.e. with libxml), or I tried to make an entirely xml-free solution. I hope you can solve what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I found solution!

```
DECLARE @xmlDoc XML;

;WITH TEMP_TABLE (NAME, AGE)
AS
(
-- select code here
)
SELECT @xmlDoc = (SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... FOR XML AUTO);
```